# Can I set API names of Picklist values seperately?

Tags: api, picklist

I'm making a picklist with 385-ish values. I want these values to have different API names than their label value. Is there any easier way to edit the API names rather than one at a time?

Comment: what have you thought of doing or researched? Is there any structure to the API names where you could programmatically set it to save time (ex. copy of label value + [certain string]).

Comment: You could do this with something like DX, but not in the UI.

Answer (score 0):

As per your concern,I understood that you would like to change the API names of the 365 picklist values at the same time.So,I would suggest you to capture the metadata file for the picklist on which you need to change and then replace all the old API names with new API names in the metadata.xml file.Once,you have changed the API names then you can re-deploy the picklist field which will update the values at a time.You can use the below sample package.xml to retrieve the picklist field.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?> 
<Package xmlns="http://soap.sforce.com/2006/04/metadata">   
  <types>     
    <members>Object.fieldName</members>   
      <name>CustomField</name>   
  </types>  
 <version>48.0</version> 
</Package>
```

Once,you retreived the customfield then you will be able to see the sample Object.xml file as below:

```
<valueSet>    
         <valueSetDefinition>        
         <sorted>false</sorted>   
              <value>  
                   <fullName>No1</fullName>    
                 <default>false</default>  
                   <label>No</label>   
              </value>       
          <value>      
               <fullName>Yess</fullName>   
                  <default>false</default> 
                    <label>Yess</label>  
               </value>          
   </valueSetDefinition>    
     </valueSet>

Here,you can change the API name of the picklist value on <fullName>No1</fullName> tag for each and every picklist value to update the API names at the same.
```

Thank you and please feel free to reach out if, you have any other concerns on the same.